# Reference: set with two coherent group structures.

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, reference-request

Do the sets with two group structures which are coherent in some nontrivial sense appear somewhere in mathematics as appropriate structures to investigate?

If so what are the areas where they appear and what are examples of their use?

Is there some textbooks, articles studying such structures?

Comment: Well, I'm not sure what you consider "nontrivial", but the [Eckmann-Hilton argument](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Eckmann%E2%80%93Hilton_argument) says that one very natural notion of "coherence" implies the two groups structures must be the same (and commutative).

Comment: If you mention the case of $Hom(C,G)$ where $C$ is a cogroup object and $G$ is a group object in a category with zero, where the two group notions coincide, Yes I am aware of such fact and would call such relationship trivial it the context. 
Actually I ask for the cases where the two structures are non-isomorphic but related somehow, coherent is some sense.